# Data not being saved in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an app with React js and firebase. When signing Up, firebase create the user and makes the alert I want but the data I want to save in firestore is not being saved. If I use the hendleSighUp function without the checkUser, it works. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you, sorry to bother you.

```
  const checkUser = async (avatar) => {
var docRef = fb.firestore().collection("links").doc(user2);
var doc = await docRef.get();
if (doc.exists) {
  //invalidUsername(true);
  console.log("error");
} else {
  handleSignUp();
  console.log("Working");
  //history.push("/");
}
```

};

```
const handleSignUp = () => {
clearErrors();
fb.auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // send verification mail.
    userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
    handleLogOut();
    fb.firestore()
      .collection("links")
      .doc("Andres")
      .set({ name: "Andres" });
    alert("Email sent");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    switch (err.code) {
      case "auth/email-already-in-use":
      case "auth/invalid-email":
        setEmailError(err.message);
        break;
      case "auth/weak-password":
        setPasswordError("Contrasena debil");
        break;
    }
  });
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I would make the function async and use await while setting the document to make sure the promise is resolved and also as alert is synchronous do it'll will block any code execution until its dismissed. Because you are not using await the alert will trigger right away.

```
fb.auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(async (userCredential) => {
    //  ^^^^^
   // send verification mail.
    userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
    handleLogOut();
    await fb.firestore()
    ^^^^^
      .collection("links")
      .doc("Andres")
      .set({ name: "Andres" });
    alert("Email sent");
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still doesn't work. Any other idea? Thank you.

Comment: @AndresPelaez add an await before `userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification()`. Also what is handleLogout? Is it logging user out? If yes, then it maybe your security that are denying writes if any. Also no errors in logs?

Comment: Thank you again but still not working. No error.

Comment: I'd try removing everything like send verification email and handleLogout and then try... can you please share code for handle logout and your security rules?